# Spring AOP - @Around Error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I've looked at the other SO questions and none of them apply. Any thoughts on why @Before works, but @Around does not?

Working off the source here:
http://www.captaindebug.com/2013/07/auditing-spring-mvc-webapp-with-aspectj.html#.VhUeIxNViko

This works fine:

```
@Before("execution(public String com.captaindebug.audit.controller.*Controller.*(..)) && @annotation(auditAnnotation)")
        public void auditScreen(JoinPoint joinPoint,Audit auditAnnotation) {...}
```

But this fails with the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Initialization
>   of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in
>   pointcut

```
@Around("execution(public String com.captaindebug.audit.controller.*Controller.*(..)) && @annotation(auditAnnotation)")
public void profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Audit auditAnnotation) throws Throwable {...)
```

This also didn't work:

```
    @Pointcut("execution(public String com.captaindebug.audit.controller.*Controller.*(..))")
    public void controllerMethods() {}

    @Around("controllerMethods()")
    public void profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {}
```

Comment: Using a @Poincut annotated method yields the same error?

Comment: If you've isolated the error around the pointcut for `execution(public String com.captaindebug.audit.controller.*Controller.*(..))` I suggest you trace the error down from a much more permisive pointcut definition like `execution(* com.captaindebug.audit.controller..*(..))` and keep adding constraints to the poincut till the error pops up again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Around` has to return something.

```
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Audit auditAnnotation) throws Throwable {
  ...
  Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
  ...
  return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I was actually returning something, but the return type had to be Object not void.

Comment: @Charlie Of course. I copied your signature and forgot to change it :/ `@Before` and `@After` let you do something additional. `@Around` on the other hand is basically a proxy, so the method has to act like the real one, including returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try splitting the pointcut definitions and aspect like so?

```
@Pointcut("execution(public String com.captaindebug.audit.controller.*Controller.*(..))")
public void controllerMethods() {}

@Pointcut("@annotation(auditAnnotation)")
public void annotatedMethod(Audit auditAnnotation) {}

@Pointcut("annotatedMethod() && controllerMethods()")
public void annotationDrivenControllerMethodsPointcut() {}

@Around("annotationDrivenControllerMethodsPointcut()")
public void profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Audit auditAnnotation) throws Throwable {...)
```

Some details from [Pointcut javadoc](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/aspectj5rt-api/index.html?org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut.html) documentation

> When compiling without debug info, or when interpreting pointcuts at runtime, the names of any arguments used in the pointcut are not available.

Comment: I already tried something like that where I removed the annotation and got the same error. Your snipper gives an "Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 0" even after changing the annotation to @Around("annotationDrivenControllerMethodsPointcut()")

Comment: Hmmm could you try one more thing as well please. Instead of `@Pointcut("@annotation(auditAnnotation)")` use the annotation's FQCN like so `@Pointcut(value="@annotation(com.captaindebug.audit.Audit)",argNames="auditAnnotation")`. Just make sure you update the FQCN `com.captaindebug.audit.Audit` with the proper one as per your packaging

Comment: Also, I assume it has nothing to do with this statement in the doc - "@Pointcut annotation (the method serving as the pointcut signature must have a void return type" that's just saying that controllerMethods() has to be void right?

Comment: That's right, all @Pointcut annotated methods must be void

Answer (score 0):

After my repeated tests
经过我的反复测试
@Around(value ="@annotation(oneAnnotaions) && args(object,..) ",argNames = "joinPoint,object," +
"oneAnnotaions")
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,Object object,com.xxx.annotaions.OneAnnotaions oneAnnotaions)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please update your answer to be in English so others may understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
After my repeated tests
经过我的反复测试
  @Around(value ="@annotation(oneAnnotaions) && args(object,..) ",argNames = "joinPoint,object," +
            "oneAnnotaions")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,Object object,com.xxx.annotaions.OneAnnotaions oneAnnotaions)
```